# vba - increment through 2 list at a time

Tags: excel, vba

i'm trying to update a sheet depending on values in another sheet.
I made 2 lists, with each one linked to the other.
but when i increment one list is going to a cell +1 and the other one is incrementing occrectly.

Here is an exemple.

```
B16 = 'PL_GROWTH(CUSTOM)'!CN88/1000
C16 = 'PL_GROWTH(CUSTOM)'!CN99/1000
D16 = 'PL_GROWTH(CUSTOM)'!CN76/1000
```

here is my function:

```
Sub UpdateMGMT(ws As Worksheet)
    Dim sourceRangeGrowth As Range, targetRangeGrowth As Range, i As Integer, j As Integer
    
    ' Set up the source and target ranges
    Set sourceRangeGrowth = Sheets("PL_GROWTH(CUSTOM)").Range("CN88,CN99,CN76,CN110,CN191,CN191,CN253,CN67,CN307,CN307,CN94,CN105,CN82,CN116,CN192,CN192,CN254,CN308,CN308,CN95,CN106,CN83,CN117,CN193,CN193,CN255,CN309,CN309")
    Set targetRangeGrowth = ws.Range("B16,C16,D16,G16,H16,J16,O16,P16,Q16,S16,B18,C18,D18,G18,H18,J18,O18,Q18,S18,B19,C19,D19,G19,H19,J19,O19,Q19,S19")
    
    ' Copy data from source to target, handling division by zero errors
    j = 1
    For Each cell In sourceRangeGrowth
        Debug.Print "Copying data from cell " & cell.Address(False, False) & " (value: " & cell.Value & ") to cell " & targetRangeGrowth(j).Address(False, False)
        If cell.Value = 0 Then
            targetRangeGrowth(j).Value = 0
            Debug.Print "Value copied: 0"
        Else
            targetRangeGrowth(j).Value = cell.Value / 1000
            Debug.Print "Value copied: " & targetRangeGrowth(j).Value
        End If
        j = j + 1
    Next cell
End Sub
```

here are some logs

Copying data from cell CN88 (value: 147905.714482528) to cell B16
Value copied: 147.905714482528

Copying data from cell CN99 (value: 111501.254016756) to cell B17
Value copied: 111.501254016756

It should be C16 and not B17

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing `targetRangeGrowth(j).Select` to `targetRangeGrowth.Areas(j).Select`. Since the cells in the target range are specified individually, Excel treats them as separate areas.

```
Sub UpdateMGMT(ws As Worksheet)
    Dim sourceRangeGrowth As Range, targetRangeGrowth As Range, i As Integer, j As Integer
    
    ' Set up the source and target ranges
    Set sourceRangeGrowth = Sheets("PL_GROWTH(CUSTOM)").Range("CN88,CN99,CN76,CN110,CN191,CN191,CN253,CN67,CN307,CN307,CN94,CN105,CN82,CN116,CN192,CN192,CN254,CN308,CN308,CN95,CN106,CN83,CN117,CN193,CN193,CN255,CN309,CN309")
    Set targetRangeGrowth = ws.Range("B16,C16,D16,G16,H16,J16,O16,P16,Q16,S16,B18,C18,D18,G18,H18,J18,O18,Q18,S18,B19,C19,D19,G19,H19,J19,O19,Q19,S19")
    
    ' Copy data from source to target, handling division by zero errors
    j = 1
    For Each cell In sourceRangeGrowth
        Debug.Print "Copying data from cell " & cell.Address(False, False) & " (value: " & cell.Value & ") to cell " & targetRangeGrowth.Areas(j).Address(False, False)
        If cell.Value = 0 Then
            targetRangeGrowth.Areas(j).Value = 0
            Debug.Print "Value copied: 0"
        Else
            targetRangeGrowth.Areas(j).Value = cell.Value / 1000
            Debug.Print "Value copied: " & targetRangeGrowth.Areas(j).Value
        End If
        j = j + 1
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Note that you should also `Dim` all variables, such as `Dim cell as Range`.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that a range defined by comma-separated cell addresses creates an `Area` for each value. The following code, for example, would output $B$1:

```
Set rng = Sheet1.Range("A1,B1")
Debug.Print rng.Areas(2).Address
```

In your code, the iterator goes beyond the end of a range. In these cases the cell in the next row down is returned. So the following code would return $A$2 (which is the problem your code is experiencing):

```
Set rng = Sheet1.Range("A1,B1")
Debug.Print rng(2).Address
```

You need to revise this line to include the area object:

```
targetRangeGrowth.Areas(j).Value = cell.Value / 1000
```

The reason that your `For Each` loop still works is that it iterates the cells in the Areas.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is going to the next row as you could see in the VBE when typing `targetRangeGrowth(` it should show `_Default([RowIndex],[ColumnIndex])` so your "j" is just going to the next row as it would in a contiguous range.

Here are some examples on [how to loop over non-contiguous ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568141/vba-loop-over-a-non-contiguous-range) but already being in a loop and having to go hand in hand with said loop, you could work with an array instead (since you're hardcoding it anyway).

Here's with looping through the cells:

```
Sub UpdateMGMT(ws As Worksheet)
    Dim sourceRangeGrowth As Range, targetRangeGrowth As Range, i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim arr()
    
    ' Set up the source and target ranges
    Set sourceRangeGrowth = Sheets("PL_GROWTH(CUSTOM)").Range("CN88,CN99,CN76,CN110,CN191,CN191,CN253,CN67,CN307,CN307,CN94,CN105,CN82,CN116,CN192,CN192,CN254,CN308,CN308,CN95,CN106,CN83,CN117,CN193,CN193,CN255,CN309,CN309")
    arr = Array("B16", "C16", "D16", "G16", "H16", "J16", "O16", "P16", "Q16", "S16", "B18", "C18", "D18", "G18", "H18", "J18", "O18", "Q18", "S18", "B19", "C19", "D19", "G19", "H19", "J19", "O19", "Q19", "S19")
    
    ' Copy data from source to target, handling division by zero errors
    j = 0 'arrays like this start at index 0
    For Each cell In sourceRangeGrowth
        Debug.Print "Copying data from cell " & cell.Address(False, False) & " (value: " & cell.Value & ") to cell " & arr(j)
        If cell.Value = 0 Then
            ws.Range(arr(j)).Value = 0
            Debug.Print "Value copied: 0"
        Else
            ws.Range(arr(j)).Value = cell.Value / 1000
            Debug.Print "Value copied: " & ws.Range(arr(j)).Value
        End If
        j = j + 1
    Next cell
End Sub
```

But since they're normally the same length, you might as well do it on both like so:

```
Sub UpdateMGMT_V2(ws As Worksheet) 'notice I changed the name here to have a difference
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim arr1(), arr2(), wsPL As Worksheet
    
    Set wsPL = Sheets("PL_GROWTH(CUSTOM)")
    ' Set up the source and target ranges
    arr1 = Array("CN88", "CN99", "CN76", "CN110", "CN191", "CN191", "CN253", "CN67", "CN307", "CN307", "CN94", "CN105", "CN82", "CN116", "CN192", "CN192", "CN254", "CN308", "CN308", "CN95", "CN106", "CN83", "CN117", "CN193", "CN193", "CN255", "CN309", "CN309")
    arr2 = Array("B16", "C16", "D16", "G16", "H16", "J16", "O16", "P16", "Q16", "S16", "B18", "C18", "D18", "G18", "H18", "J18", "O18", "Q18", "S18", "B19", "C19", "D19", "G19", "H19", "J19", "O19", "Q19", "S19")
    
    ' Copy data from source to target, handling division by zero errors
    '0/1000 is no issue, 1000/0 is, you're not dividing by zero in your example, just dividing 0
    'but I'm keeping your structure in case you need it as such
    For j = 0 To UBound(arr1)
        Debug.Print "Copying data from cell " & arr1(j) & " (value: " & wsPL.Range(arr1(j)) & ") to cell " & arr2(j)
        If wsPL.Range(arr1(j)).Value = 0 Then
            ws.Range(arr2(j)).Value = 0
            Debug.Print "Value copied: 0"
        Else
            ws.Range(arr2(j)).Value = wsPL(arr1(j)).Value / 1000
            Debug.Print "Value copied: " & ws.Range(arr2(j)).Value
        End If
    Next j
End Sub
```

You could also place the values in different arrays to have even less interactions with Excel but this should be understandable/doable enough. If you'd be dealing with more cells, it'd be a hassle to keep hardcoding like this anyway.

Feel free to ask questions :)